# Drawing on the MapFragment, while keeping some elements visible

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm developing an application that has the following goal:

- Using the google maps android API 2  I get my current position, and as I start walking the application starts drawing the route I take
- The twist is that the map is a "blind" map. Meaning the map is hidden, only the Marker of my current position and a dotted line of my route is shown.

Keep in mind I'm a novice developing to Android, so please be specific. (Thank you)

I managed to create the map, get my current position and zoom in to it (Had no sens to see the whole planet while i want only my current position). And it's pretty accurate so far.

The thing is I don't know what should I do from this point on.
Basicly I need a white View between the Marker and the real map. Also as I advance that View should always be on, over the MapFragment/MapView. Also I wish to keep the zoom and drag functionality's of the MapFragment.

How can I achieve this?

At this point I'm opened to any solutions.

(Been browsing for a few days now the developers site, I have seen that with the ViewOverlay class I can put messages over the map, but I'm not sure what would the correct aproach be in my case...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide the whole map behind the white view I would use `Polygon` class [Polygon](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon.html) Even if you specify `Polygon` to cover the whole map `Marker`s will be still displayed in front of it and as so user's current position marker will be visible. You also will be able to zoom and drag.

To draw line on map use `Polyline` class [Polyline](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline.html) It will draw users path as a polyline. If you want to stick with dotted line you can use `Circle` objects to create it. [Circle](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle.html)

Comment: Thanksfor your reply, today I will try it out, and get back to you.